# How to detect change of select from ajax loaded content

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, select

I know .change() can be used to detect changed on my document, but this only seems to work if the select element exists upon loading.

I have a page that calls in numerous select elements via ajax and I need to detect changes for each select.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two usual ways to do this are:

1. Call `.change()` with an appropriate selector *after* adding the elements to the page (from in your Ajax success handler, or wherever).
2. Setup a delegated event handler attached to a parent or ancestor element that does exist at page load (`document`, if there is no closer ancestor).

Here's how to create a delegated handler using the [`.on()` method](http://api.jquery.com/on/):

```
$("#idOfAncestorThatExistsOnLoad").on("change", "selectorOfDynamicElements", function() {
     // do something here
});
```

When the change event bubbles up to the ancestor element jQuery automatically tests whether it originated with an element matching the selector in the second parameter, and only calls the handler function if it does match.

Comment: Thanks, works nicely although as I'm on 1.3.2 had to use .bind instead of .on.

Comment: Assuming you're talking about the code that I showed, which was my option (2), you can't do that with `.bind()` because it doesn't let you do delegated handlers. For a delegated handler in 1.3.2 you'd need to use `.live()`. (You could use `.bind()` or `.click()` for option (1).)

Comment: $('.custom_reports_right').bind('change', 'select', function(){}); is working nicely

Comment: I think it's treating the second parameter as the `[data]` parameter (as mentioned in [the doco](http://api.jquery.com/bind/)), but it still works because the event bubbles up. I'd be surprised if you get the "right" value of `this` in your event handler though.

Answer (score 0):

A good approach is to bind the event with specific selectors

```
$(document).on('change', 'select', handlerFunction);
```

Now your event handler is binded to `document` but affects only `select` elements. If you load some data with AJAX the handler will work immediately with the new selects.

Comment: Event delegation ... `$('#container').on('change', 'select', function(){})` The event handler is attached to the container receiving the content ..

Answer (score 0):

You could do as,

In `select`

```
<select name="demo" id="demo"  onchange="selectRequest('demo');">
```

In `js` file

```
function selectRequest(id) // id of select
{
   var selectVal = $('#' + id).val(); // currently selected 
   // rest do with the val
}
```

No need to give in `$(document).ready()`

Here is the working code,

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.0.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            function selectRequest(id) // id of select
            {
                var selectVal = $(id).val(); // currently selected 
                alert(selectVal)
                // rest do with the val
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <select name="demo" id="demo"  onchange="selectRequest(this);"> 
            <option value='1'>1</option>
            <option value='2'>2</option>
        </select>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Assuming for the sake of argument that an inline handler is a good idea, why wouldn't you just do `onchange="selectRequest(this);"`?

Comment: This way my first thought and I know it would work, but I wanted to learn a cleaner work around.

Comment: Yes can do, so in `selectRequest(id)` value can be get as `$('#' + id.id).val();`

Comment: My point was if you passed `this` then in the function you just say `$(this).val()`...